# Convert double to UInt16

Tags: c#

I'm making a function that will allow the user to pass a double value, and then return a UInt16.

This is my code:

```
public static UInt16 Value_To_BatteryVoltage(double value)
    {
        var ret = ((int)value << 8); 
        var retMod = (value % (int)value) * 10; 
        return (UInt16)(ret + retMod);
    }
```

Basically what it does is as follows, function call:

```
Value_To_BatteryVoltage(25.10)
```

Will return: 6401

I can check the result by doing:

```
public static double VoltageLevel(UInt16 value)
    {
        return ((value & 0xFF00) >> 8) + ((value & 0x00FF) / 10.0);
    }
```

This is working as expected, BUT, if I do:

```
Value_To_BatteryVoltage(25.11) //notice the 0.11
```

I get the wrong result, because:

```
public static UInt16 Value_To_BatteryVoltage(double value)
    {
        var ret = ((int)value << 8); // returns 6400 OK
        var retMod = (value % (int)value) * 10; //returns 0.11 x 10 = 1.1 WRONG!
        return (UInt16)(ret + retMod); //returns 6400, because (UInt16)(6400 + 1.1) = 6401 same as 25.10 so I've lost precision
    }
```

So the question is, is there some way to do this kind of conversion without losing precision?

Comment: This is a very strange kind of conversion - and if you're really that interested in the *precise decimal digits* you should probably be using `decimal` in the first place.

Comment: A `UInt16` can hold 65,536 different values, while a `double` can hold around 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 different values. It's not clear how you could possibly do the conversion without ever losing precision.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to store the Characteristic (interger-part) in the first 8 bits of UInt16. And the Mantissa (fractional-part) in the second 8 bits.

This is one way to do it. I treat the double like a string and split it at the decimal. For example:

```
    public static UInt16 Value_To_BatteryVoltage(double value)
    {
        string[] number = value.ToString().Split('.');
        UInt16 c = (UInt16)(UInt16.Parse(number[0]) << 8);
        UInt16 m = UInt16.Parse(number[1]);
        return (UInt16)(c + m);
    }
```

And here is the output:

[image: Code Output]

Comment: I like this solutoin, however, if the m has too much significance then this will interfere with the c value.  Would they need to be orthogonal?  Should you limit the length of the m value to 2 digits to ensure there will be no interference as once you get to values over .256 you will see the issue.  I guess there is a similar issue if the number[0] is too large and the << 8 then truncates it

Comment: I am deleting my answer, and I think this answer suffers from the same weakness, ie: 25.01 and 25.1 would be encoded as the same UInt16's.

Comment: I think you could avoid the above issue by using something like :`string[] number = value.ToString("#0.000",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');`